# Progressive web app, separate pages in a website

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Didn't really know how to title this but my question is if its possible to say I have a website with users and each user has a profile page with their information, contact info and sharing buttons. Is it possible to allow PWA on each profile page with the add to home button? So then it creates a short cut straight to the users profile page as a PWA instead of going on the browser again.

Comment: Yes you can do it

Comment: Only thing you need is to have different manifest file  for each profile specific url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but you need to use your server generate manifest.json for each and let server cache that file